# using couchdb from java through ektorp resiliently

Tags: java, couchdb, pojo, ektorp

how can I instantiate a Pojo from a couchdb document even if fields are missing in the document - how can I tell ektorp to ignore the field it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know really what you mean, if the property doesn't exists for the pojo it will be null (or 0/true for primitive types) after deserialization from CouchDB.